# Как в список добавить ключ словаря?

Tags: python, словари, список

Необходимо из словаря взять ключ и добавить его в пустой список.

Вот код, который я пытался реализовать, но он добавляет не ключ, а значение:

```py
last_order = {
    'XMRUSDT': ['sell', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'usd': ['sell', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}
requestedFutures = []
requestedFutures.append(last_order['XMRUSDT'])
print(requestedFutures[0])
```

Comment: Ну так ведь ``last_order['XMRUSDT']`` и есть значение. А ключ - ``'XMRUSDT'``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы вернуть ключи, используйте метод `keys()` для словаря

Пример

```py
last_order = {
    'XMRUSDT': ['sell', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'usd': ['sell', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}
requestedFutures = []
requestedFutures.append(list(last_order.keys())[0])
# или без keys()
requestedFutures.append(list(last_order)[0])
```

В данном случае учитывайте, что тип данных `dict` не упорядоченный и нужно быть уверенным в том какой ключ вы добавляете

Добавить все ключи можно так

```py
requestedFutures += list(last_order)
```